# Paypal DoDirectPayment API is not sending the notifications to Sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

I am using the DoDirectPayment and DoCapture paypal API(s) to authorize and capture the Credit Card Payments via Paypal. But the Problem is that I am not getting any notification in Sandbox when the payment is authorized and captured. I get the Notifications only when the PaymentAction = 'Sale' but the notifications are not coming when  PaymentAction = 'Authorization'.

Comment: You should be getting the IPN for authorization and capture also without any issues . Can you post any transaction id for the authorize type payment ?

Comment: I am not using any IPN. I am using Direct Payment Method. I am getting the transaction ID when the method is called. but I only get the notification in Sandbox if the paymentAction='Sale' but I do not get the notfication when I only authorize the credit card by using paymentaction = 'Authorize'. Everything is working fine but I just can't get the confirmation notifications in Sandbox

Comment: What notification are you expecting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156374/paypal-rest-api-php-sdk-successful-transactions-not-showing-in-sandbox-mode-s